# How to remove escape sequence off NSString(or NSMutableString) in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

For example, i have an `NSString` containing "\134x00\134x00\134x00\134x41".
I am grabbing that string from an html page tag which contains "\x00\x00\x00\x41" (the exact value i need the string to contain), so probably that is why the \134 escape sequence is there.

What i have tried so far is:

`[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\134" withString:@"\\"];`

(replace \134 with just ).
But after executing this line of code, when i try to print the string to the console, it prints again with the escape sequence.

How can i unescape the string so it contains only "\x00\x00\x00\x41", or in other words when i print it it prints the letter "A"?

---

### Edit:

Here is how the string is assigned:

```
[webview evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('title')[‌​0].innerHTML;" completionHandler:^(NSString *string, NSError *error) { 
    if(error) { 
        NSLog(@"no 'title' tag"); 
    } else if (string && ![string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { 
        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"134" withString:@""]; 
    }
}];
```

Comment: You should do it like [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"134" withString:@""];

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but when i print the string, it contains the escape sequence. It seems like the NSString object automatically escapes it when it finds "\x"...

Comment: What is it printing now?

Comment: \134x00\134x00\134x00\134x41 - same as before.

Comment: Please show us your code about how are you assigning value to string variable.

Comment: Does `\134x00` result in any character, what does it do? How does the 134 even get in there, where does it come from?

Comment: This is the peace of code where i grab the innerHTML from an html tag on the page:

`[webview evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;" completionHandler:^(NSString *string, NSError *error)
{       
 if(error){
            NSLog(@"no 'title' tag");
            } else if (string && ![string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){ 
                string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"134" withString:@""];`
}



And this is the html tag:
`<title>\x00\x00\x00\x41</title>`

Comment: \134x00 does not result in any character, since the hex is escaped

Comment: The instance method `- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` will return a newly created `NSString`. So if you try to print out the old `string` variable you will get the unmodified previous string. You should have a `newString` variable, store the result returned from that operation to it and then print/use as you like that `newString`.

Comment: @nayem unfortunately it gets escaped again... :/ tried assigning it to a new string, but when i `NSLog("%@", newString)` it still prints it with the escape sequence..

Comment: After debugging a bit, figured out that the 134 sequence is added when NSString recognizes the "\" character.

Comment: `@"\134"` should be `@"\\134"` no? XCode doesn't give a warning?